# how to remove attribute selected option inside modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem in removing the attribute selected in the option

my select is inside the modal when my page load option build dynamically like this

```
 <select class="form-control" id="petselect" name="petselect">
          <?php
               foreach ($pest as $pet){
                    echo "<option value='".$pet->id."'>$pet->name</option>";
                }
          ?>
  </select>
```

when I edit the form the modal will show and I selected the default pet->id

```
<select class="form-control" id="petselect" name="petselect">
    <option value="1">pet1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">pet2</option>
    <option value="3">pet3</option>
    <option value="4">pet4</option>
    <option value="5">pet5</option>
    <option value="6">pet6</option>
    <option value="7">pet7</option>
    <option value="8">pet8</option>
    <option value="9">pet9</option>
</select>
```

Now when I change it to pet5 and submit the form via ajax, and my modal will hide,
when I edit again the option selected pet5 is displayed but when I view source
this is how it looks like, 2 selected attribute.

```
<select class="form-control" id="petselect" name="petselect">
    <option value="1">pet1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">pet2</option>
    <option value="3">pet3</option>
    <option value="4">pet4</option>
    <option value="5" selected="selected">pet5</option>
    <option value="6">pet6</option>
    <option value="7">pet7</option>
    <option value="8">pet8</option>
    <option value="9">pet9</option>
</select>
```

this is my js to add selected attribute,when I edit the form

```
$('#petselect option')
  .filter(function() { return  $(this).val()  === petID; })
  .attr('selected',true);
```

and code for my modal when it hides.

```
 $('#petselectmodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#petselect option:selected')
                .removeAttr('selected');
            });
```

Comment: Can you try this? `$('#petselect option[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').attr('selected',true);`

Comment: in your model code use following code $('option:selected', 'select[name="petselect"]').removeAttr('selected');
instead of $('#petselect option:selected')
                .removeAttr('selected');

Comment: `$('#dropdownid').val('selectedvalue'); ` directly setting the value should auto set the select too

Comment: FYI `selected` is a property and you should use `.prop()`. This should not be done on the Option level but the Select level. The Options are basically a visual indicator, but the element that has the Name and thus the Value is the Select element. Use `$('#petselect").val(5);` and then the form will read this value instead. Plus HTML will update the Option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be done on the `<option>` but on the `<select>` level. The Options are basically a visual indicators. The element that has the Name and thus the Value is the Select element. Use `$('#petselect").val(5);` and then the form will read this value instead. Plus HTML will update the Option too.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#petselect").val(5);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="petselect" name="petselect">
  <option value="1">pet1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">pet2</option>
  <option value="3">pet3</option>
  <option value="4">pet4</option>
  <option value="5">pet5</option>
  <option value="6">pet6</option>
  <option value="7">pet7</option>
  <option value="8">pet8</option>
  <option value="9">pet9</option>
</select>
<button>Change</button>
```

You can do it manually if you so choose.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#petselect").val("");
    $("#petselect option").prop("selected", false);
    $("#petselect").val(5);
    $("#petselect option[value='" + 5 + "']").prop("selected", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="petselect" name="petselect">
  <option value="1">pet1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">pet2</option>
  <option value="3">pet3</option>
  <option value="4">pet4</option>
  <option value="5">pet5</option>
  <option value="6">pet6</option>
  <option value="7">pet7</option>
  <option value="8">pet8</option>
  <option value="9">pet9</option>
</select>
<button>Change</button>
```